# FOR UPDATE inside a transaction doesn't lock rows

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, locking

I made this test to select a row, which I created previously, from two threads:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
) ENGINE=InnoDB 

    var t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=test;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id from customers where id = 8534 FOR UPDATE;", conn, trans))
                {
                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter t1: " + reader.Read());
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Exit t1");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }));

    var t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
    {
        using (var conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;Uid=root;Pwd=test;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id from customers where id = 8534", conn))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter t2: " + cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                Console.WriteLine("Exit t2");
            }
        }
    }));

    t1.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(400);
    t2.Start();

    t1.Join();
    t2.Join();
```

And the result that I get is:

```
Enter t1: True
Enter t2: 8534
Exit t2
Exit t1
```

Shouldn't the FOR UPDATE in thread 1 prevent thread 2 to read the row until it releases the transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't the `FOR UPDATE` in thread 1 prevent thread 2 to read the row until it releases the transaction?

No.

But it would prevent thread 2 from writing this row (or reading it with `FOR UPDATE` clause as well).

In default transaction isolation level (that is `REPEATABLE READ`), `SELECT` statements do not place any locks on rows they read.

For a `SELECT` statement to lock you should instruct it to lock (by using `FOR UPDATE`, `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` or setting the reader's transaction isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE`).

From the [**docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-consistent-read.html):

> Consistent read is the default mode in which `InnoDB` processes `SELECT` statements in `READ COMMITTED` and `REPEATABLE READ` isolation levels. A consistent read does not set any locks on the tables it accesses, and therefore other sessions are free to modify those tables at the same time a consistent read is being performed on the table.

and

> `InnoDB` uses a consistent read for select in clauses like `INSERT INTO ... SELECT, UPDATE ... (SELECT)`, and `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` that do not specify `FOR UPDATE` or `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` if the `innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog` option is set and the isolation level of the transaction is not set to `SERIALIZABLE`. Thus, no locks are set on rows read from the selected table. Otherwise, InnoDB uses stronger locks and the `SELECT` part acts like `READ COMMITTED`, where each consistent read, even within the same transaction, sets and reads its own fresh snapshot.